# Laravel Eloquent with()-> returning null

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use Eloquent to get a specific product that has a `brand_id` column that maps to a `brands` table, the `brand` array is coming back empty.

Is there anything obvious here that needs to be changed?

```
$product = Product::with('images')->with('brand')->select($fields)->where('display', '=', 1)->find($id);
```

//Product model

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    ...
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Brand');
    }
```

//Brand model

```
class Brand extends Eloquent {
...
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Product');
}
```

Comment: have You checked it with: $brand = $product->brand();   ?

Comment: What fields are in the `$fields` variable ?

Comment: Awesome question thank you! And great answers to the guys below. Saved me time on my project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have this:

```
$product = Product::with('images', 'brand')
                  ->select($fields)
                  ->where('display', 1)
                  ->find($id);
```

You are getting `null` for `brand` and it could be because you have some specific fields and most probably you didn't select the `foreing_key` from the `products` table that creates the relationship with `Brand`, so if your `products` table contains the `foreign_key` (probably `brand_id`) of `brand` table then you have to select that `foreign_key` from the `products` table too. So, just add that `foreign_key/brand_id` in the `$fields` variable. Without the relation builder key (`FK`) the `Brand` won't be loaded.

Comment: Genius. Thank you, you were exactly right about $fields.

Comment: Just to tack this on here - if you're specifying any columns with your "with" statements, you'll need to make sure you include the "id" column, or else you'll get null again. I assume "id" is required to match to the foreign key - but that's something I would have just assumed that the "with" statement did on its own.

Comment: upvote! just for the way you wrote this answer :)